# Footnote with fancy page style

Tags: fancyhdr, pagestyle

i have a problem with footnote and the pagestyle fancy. I tryed to use some commands as \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}, \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 or with geometry package but i did not find a solution
Thanks for help !

```
\documentclass[svgnames, palatino]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\addtolength{\footnotesep}{2mm}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\title{}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[scale=.15]{miashs}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{blabla}
blabla
 cf partie : \ref{réorganisation} \ref{réorganisation}\footnote{La couleur rouge souligne un lien cliquable}), 

\section{réorganisation\label{réorganisation}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: Sorry, i add the little part where i have the problem

Comment: Minimal means removing as much code (and thus as much packages) as possible. But thanks, now we have something to start with.

Comment: something lighter, sorry an other time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[svgnames, palatino]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\makebox[0pt][l]%
{\hspace*{-1.75cm}\raisebox{-6ex}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}}}
\begin{document}
\section{blabla}
blabla\footnote{La couleur rouge souligne un lien cliquable} \lipsum[1-20]
\newpage
\section{réorganisation\label{réorganisation}}
blabla\footnote{La couleur rouge souligne un lien cliquable} \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hm, i have to remove my fancy style on this page. If a can keep it i will, if i cannot i will do this., thank you

Comment: @AlexiaB.I have not cancelled the fancyfoot style: the image is still there. What I have removed is the `\footrule`

Comment: @AlexiaB.See if my update suits you.

Comment: i want to keep the line, your update is exactly i want, thank you very much for help